# how to intersect two "selects" and then put another condition for the result

Tags: sql, intersection

I want to intersect two "select" queries and then put another condition for the whole result. I mean:

```
(select ... intersect select ...) where ...
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on your flavour of database
Oracle (for example) will allow this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ( SELECT *
           FROM TABLE_A
         INTERSECT
         SELECT *
           FROM TABLE_B
       )
WHERE <conditions>
```

Answer (score 2):

Select * From (select ... intersect select ...) as intersectedTable where ...

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a derived table.

```
    SELECT value,data FROM
    (SELECT value,data FROM table1 union select value,data from table2) t
    WHERE value=5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are intersecting, any condition you put on the either of the two SELECTs will also apply to the whole condition...

So, the easiest way is to just

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE (condition)
INTERSECT
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE (another condition)
```